# Where clause using alias column with IF and IFNULL

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias, where-clause, ifnull

I have an mysql query like below:

```
SELECT 
        sppt_ticket.*, 
        IF(sppt_read_support_ticket.ID_aks_user IS NULL,'N', 'Y') AS `read_status`, 
        IFNULL(readcomment.total_comment, 0) AS unread_comment
    FROM 
        sppt_ticket
    LEFT JOIN 
        sppt_read_support_ticket ON 
        sppt_ticket.ID_support_ticket = sppt_read_support_ticket.ID_support_ticket AND 
        ID_aks_user = 1
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            sppt_comment.ID_support_ticket, SUM(IF(sppt_read_comment.ID_aks_user IS NULL, 1, 0)) 
    AS 
        total_comment
    FROM 
        sppt_comment
    LEFT JOIN 
        sppt_read_comment 
    ON 
        sppt_comment.ID_comment = sppt_read_comment.ID_comment 
    AND 
        sppt_read_comment.ID_aks_user = 1
    GROUP BY 
        sppt_comment.ID_support_ticket) AS readcomment ON readcomment.ID_support_ticket = sppt_ticket.ID_support_ticket
```

What I want to get in where clause is like this

```
WHERE read_status = 'Y'
```

I've tried using subquery, but still I didn't get it..
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
-- your original query as a table
SELECT 
    sppt_ticket.*, 
    IF(sppt_read_support_ticket.ID_aks_user IS NULL,'N', 'Y') AS `read_status`, 
    IFNULL(readcomment.total_comment, 0) AS unread_comment
FROM 
    sppt_ticket
LEFT JOIN 
    sppt_read_support_ticket ON 
    sppt_ticket.ID_support_ticket = sppt_read_support_ticket.ID_support_ticket AND 
    ID_aks_user = 1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        sppt_comment.ID_support_ticket, SUM(IF(sppt_read_comment.ID_aks_user IS NULL, 1, 0)) 
AS 
    total_comment
FROM 
    sppt_comment
LEFT JOIN 
    sppt_read_comment 
ON 
    sppt_comment.ID_comment = sppt_read_comment.ID_comment 
AND 
    sppt_read_comment.ID_aks_user = 1
GROUP BY 
    sppt_comment.ID_support_ticket) AS readcomment ON readcomment.ID_support_ticket = sppt_ticket.ID_support_ticket
)
as temptable
where read_status = 'Y' -- this should work
```

Or you can use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` if you do not want to treat your query as a table:

```
SELECT 
    sppt_ticket.*, 
    IF(sppt_read_support_ticket.ID_aks_user IS NULL,'N', 'Y') AS `read_status`, 
    IFNULL(readcomment.total_comment, 0) AS unread_comment
FROM 
    sppt_ticket
LEFT JOIN 
    sppt_read_support_ticket ON 
    sppt_ticket.ID_support_ticket = sppt_read_support_ticket.ID_support_ticket AND 
    ID_aks_user = 1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        sppt_comment.ID_support_ticket, SUM(IF(sppt_read_comment.ID_aks_user IS NULL, 1, 0)) 
AS 
    total_comment
FROM 
    sppt_comment
LEFT JOIN 
    sppt_read_comment 
ON 
    sppt_comment.ID_comment = sppt_read_comment.ID_comment 
AND 
    sppt_read_comment.ID_aks_user = 1
GROUP BY 
    sppt_comment.ID_support_ticket) AS readcomment ON readcomment.ID_support_ticket = sppt_ticket.ID_support_ticket
HAVING read_status = 'Y' -- use HAVING instead of WHERE
```

The reason why treating your original query as a table works is because of the way values are evaluated in the query. In your original query, the alias `read_status` cannot be used with the `WHERE` clause because the actual value might not yet be known when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated. As documented in [Section B.1.5.4, “Problems with Column Aliases”.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html) Treating it as a table ensures that the value for `read_status` has already been evaluated.

For the `HAVING` approach, MySQL created an extension to standard SQL that [permits references in the HAVING clause to aliased expressions in the select list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: seems weird, i have done that before using the subquery, but error, and now that's work.. maybe i'm too overthinking and missed something..